# how to downgrade from Magento Professional to Magento Community?

Tags: magento-community, migration

I would like to get some guidance from someone who has already done this before.

My websites (3) run on a multi store set up of Magento Professional 1.1.0.0
Since it's no longer supported, we like to move back to Magento Community

I was told that our version is equivalent to Community 1.6.1.0

I have already set up a testing server with Community 1.6.1.0 on it.

I need some instructions of proceeding from there.

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you mean Magento Enterprise?

Comment: @user2045 - No, he means **Professional Edition**, an intermediate version between CE and EE that was offered at one time and kind of petered out. And the major consideration will be dealing with User Password Encryption which is different between CE and EE, but I don't know if CE and PE used the same scheme.

Comment: Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I can help with the password issue.

What you can do is use the encryption class from PE in CE

So first some background, as it will help understand the solution.

The encryption is handled via a helper class, which is defined in `Mage_Core_Helper_Data`

```
const XML_PATH_ENCRYPTION_MODEL = 'global/helpers/core/encryption_model';
```

This class is instantiated in the same class in the method `getEncryptor`

```
$encryptionModel = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_ENCRYPTION_MODEL);
```

So, all you need to do is rewrite that helper class in your own module:

```
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <core>
                <encryption_model>YourNamespace_Login_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
            </core>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <YourNamespace_login>
                <class>YourNamespace_Login_Model</class>
            </YourNamespace_login>
        </models>
    </global>
```

then copy the file `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` from PE to your module as the file you are rewriting to : `YourNamespace_Login_Model_Encryption` and make sure it extends the core CE class using `extends Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` which will allow youto also still call the parent class method code, thus gain access to the original CE encryption model methods. (see more below about phasing out this 'hack')

The end result is that you would effectively replace CE's encryption with that what was used in PE

Phasing out this change (just a thought, no code how to make it happen):

Ultimately you'd want to get your customers into the core CE encryption, and phase out the PE encryption model

You can add a flag attribute to customers accounts, and note if they are using the PE or CE encryption, and then if on CE you can call the parent method in CE to do the work.

You'd want to make sure new password creation always fall-back to CE methods, so any new passwords are created using CE methods.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with Pro edition, but you probably need to start over with a fresh install.  Pro might have models/helpers in the eav tables that wouldn't exist anymore so you would need to clear those out.

You could then export your orders, customers, products and import them into the new store.  You should be able to copy over the local and community modules without much of an issue.  The theme might take some tinkering, or you might want to start with a new theme.

It's going to be a bit of hassle.  Downgrading isn't as easy as upgrading.

Comment: Why not just copy / create new copies of the eav tables?  A sort of 'psuedo-professional edition'